# Wordpress child theme troubleshooting

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

I am using X theme from themeco, latest version. Created a custom child theme instead of using the ones made available by them. I followed all of the instructions, the `functions.php` file loads the activation details of the parent theme, but doesn't include the other functions it needs to load. Like header, footer or any other page, even though all of the files are included in the child theme.

Should I remove them from there and just keep the `functions.php` and `style.css` files? I will try that, if it solves the problem, otherwise, the functions are just not being there. Tried to view a test code to see which header was it even displaying, I could see the test text written where the header should be but still can't see the header.

Doing an inspection through chrome I could see lots of problems related to revolution slider, js errors, will need time to debug them but would love if anyone got a quick fix for it without me racking brains all over the place.

Edit:

[Code](https://binbox.io/36yYE#6slSZAJZ)

Comment: how to help you, if we don't have any code, any error logs? just can guess, that you bad coded your child theme. and if you want escape from errors, use clear child theme with just style.css file

Comment: Added the code, it's what I used in the functions.php file. Since style.css file didn't had any css code in it besides the theme info, haven't included that. I have got the theme activated and I can just see the widgets I placed with the cornerstone. Besides that nothing else is working

Comment: I don't know how to add thee code here, since stackoverflow has it's code embedding instructions which I am unable to understand entirely, and which places my code weirdly, that's why had to place it in a link, didn't remember what other services I could use for that, so used binbox. If anyone could edit it in the question, please feel free to do that.

Comment: @SamvelAleqsanyan Had to use a clear style.css file, alas, didn't know that the child theme shouldn't include any other files than the syle.css and functions.php for it to work normally. Any editing is done within a file and copied over to the child theme in the same directory, I was copying all of the files in the thoughts that it would need them all, that was my mistake.